# Uniform convergence on $(a,b)\cap \mathbb{Q}\implies $ Uniform convergence on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ for each $n$ and it converges uniformly on $(a,b)\cap \mathbb{Q}$, prove it converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

I'm trying to solve this problem and from the given part of the problem. I felt that I should use Dini's theorem to get the result, but I'm not sure how $f_n$ converges uniformly on $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ comes to use. Am I thinking it in the wrong approach?

Comment: Are the $f_n$ monotone? Otherwise I don't see how you can use Dini's theorem.

Comment: You kinda need to prove that the sequence is equicontinuous, so maybe it's an Ascoli-Arzelà-ish thing.

Comment: I don't think you need any theorems. All you have to show is that the delta corresponding to epsilon at x is a continous function (of x).

Comment: Assume the greatest delta corresponding to epsilon for some irrational or endpoint is less than the universal delta for (a,b) intersect Q. Arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq |f_n(x)-f_n(r)|+|f_n(r)-f_m(r)|+|f_m(r)-f_m(x)|$$

Ok, so given $x$, and $n,m\geq N$ chose $r$ rational so that the first and third terms are less than $\epsilon$. The middle term will be less than $\epsilon$ for all $r$, rational. Where of course $N$ is chosen large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Each  $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f_n\to f$(say) uniformly on  $(a,b)\cap \Bbb Q$ so  $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)\cap \Bbb Q$.

> Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly on  $(a,b)\cap \Bbb Q\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ $\forall n\ge m;\forall x\in (a,b)\cap \Bbb Q$.
>
> Also each $f_n$ is uniformly continuous.Hence $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f(x)-f_m(x)|+|f_m(x)-f_m(y)|+|f_m(y)-f(y)|<\epsilon $ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.
>
> So $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)\cap \Bbb Q$ and hence can be continuously extended to $(a,b)$ and hence to $[a,b]$.

Now $\sup _{x\in (a,b)\cap \Bbb Q} |f_n-f|<\epsilon$ forall $\epsilon>0$.

Hence $|f_n(r)-f(r)|=|f_n(\lim c_n)-\lim f(c_n)|=\lim |(f_n-f)(c_n)|<\epsilon$

Hence $\sup _{x\in (a,b)\cap \Bbb Q^c} |f_n-f|<\epsilon$ forall $\epsilon>0$.

So $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$

Comment: You haven't defined $f$ on all of $[a,b]$ (we're not even given that $f_n(x)$ converges for irrational values of $x$), so how can you assert that it is continuous on $[a,b]$? I guess you mean that $f$ has a unique continuous extension to $[a,b]$. I assume this turns out to be true under the hypotheses of this problem, but is it obvious? Do we first need to argue that $f$ is *uniformly* continuous on $(a,b)\cap \mathbb Q$?

Comment: the part from f is continuous on $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ to f continuous on $[a,b]$ also confused me. It doesn't looks justified.

Comment: You do know of course that there are functions continuous on the irrationals and discontinuous on the rationals.

Comment: [Thomae's Function](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-io-EmdLQAhWJQY8KHeMKDKcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FThomae%27s_function&usg=AFQjCNFqvSif1kCsElTkjIRBKvuiZyp_PQ).